# Removing :hover class once a li element has been clicked

Tags: css, angular

All,

I have a list of items like this

```
<ul class="known-fields list-unstyled" [hidden]='!showKnownList' style="width: 25%; max-height: 400px">
    <li class="known-field" *ngFor="let knownField of knownFields" (click)="onKnownFieldClicked($event, knownField)">
        <span class="known-field-text" [ngClass]="{ 'required': knownField.required }">
            {{ knownField.label }}
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Inside my scss I have the following :

```
.known-field {
//display: block;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 4px;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-bottom: 2px;
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: pointer;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;

&:hover {
    background-color: #f2fcff;
    border-color: darken(#f2fcff, 15%);
}

.required::after {
    content: '*';
    color: #ff3300;
}

&.active {
    background-color: #f2fffc;
    border-color: darken(#f2fffc, 15%);
}
}
```

What I want to do is disable the :hover class once a user clicks on list item.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: Use an additional class to apply the effect in the first place, such as `.known-field.hoverme:hover`, and remove that class from the element after the first click, so that this selector won’t match the element any more …

Comment: I would take the css out of the :hover pseudoclass and put it into a class of itself. Then use javascript to add and remove your new class on hover/click.

Comment: Good suggestion, I moved to another class and worked!!!

Thx!!!